# SSSD list allowed users only

Tags: ldap, sssd, getent

We are using SSSD for authentication using LDAP. And I filter the user access using **simple_allow_groups** as follows:

```
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = Computer Admins
```

(**Note**: Computer Admins is a LDAP group)

Is it possible to get a list of **ONLY** allowed users using **getent** or something else??

There is an option enumeration, but this lists **all** users from LDAP. I am only interested in the **allowed** users.

Comment: Authenticaton for what?  Secure Shell?  If so, add the relevant groups to `/etc/ssh/sssd_config`'s `AllowGroups` directive once you have PAM enabled and configured.

Comment: I want get a listing of the users that are allowed by "simple_allow_groups" for e.g.

Comment: Good question.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Nope. I don’t think it is possible 

Answer (score 0):

`getent` only works if your group is a Unix group (that is, it has a `gidNumber` and is visible to the `nss` part of `sssd`). If `/etc/nsswtich.conf` is set up to look up groups via `sss`, then `getent group 'Computer Admins'` will give you a list of members of that group, transitively closed (that is, including members of groups that are themselves members of this group etc.). This list should only include users who are also Unix users (who have an `uidNumber` attribute).

If 'Computer Admins' is not a Unix group, then you'll have to work with an LDAP client (such as `ldapsearch` or `ldapvi`) to get its members and implement transitive closure yourself.